# Concatenate fields in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, string-concatenation

I have a table like this

```
id   name   value
1    Ram     a
2    John    b
3    Ram     c
4    Ram     d
5    John    e
```

I want the the output like this

```
name   value
Ram     a,c,d
John    b,e
```

Is there any way to perform this query?

**UPDATE :**

Table format :

```
id   field1   value  field2
1    val1     a       null
2    val2     b       null
3    val1     c       null
4    val2     d       null
5    null     e       val1
5    null     f       val1
5    null     g       val2
5    null     h       val2
```

Output :

```
field1   field2   value
val1      null    a,c
val2      null    b,d
null      val1    e,f
null      val2    g,h
```

Is there any way to perform this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `group_concat`

```
select
name, group_concat(value separator ',') as value
from table_name
group by name
```

Also if you want the values to be ordered you can use `order by` within `group concat` as

```
select
name, group_concat(value order by value) as value
from table_name
group by name
```

Comment: Also do not change the original question the first answer was very much correct with respect to the provided question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the modified question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen check the fiddle link in my comment which answers the modified question pretty much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value SEPARATOR ',')
AS value FROM table
GROUP BY field1, field2;
```

Answer (score 1):

use [group_concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(value) AS value FROM my_table group by name
```

Comment: try group by field1,field2

Answer (score 1):

The [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function should do the trick for you:

```
SELECT   name, GROUP_CONCAT(value) AS value
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql GROUP_CONCAT could help you. Please see example in this link https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select name,group_concat(value) from tablename group by name
```